# Unable to access H2 Database in LAN

Tags: java, swing, h2

Please go through below code that I wrote in Java Swing to connect H2 Database in LAN, I did Google but not get proper solution.

```
try {
        //192.168.0.200 is Partner IP Address
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://192.168.0.200/~/testingDB", "sa", "");
        System.out.println("Connected" + connection);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Here" + e.toString());
    }
```

I am trying to connect H2 Database that are installed on another computer using IPV4 address but I am getting below error.

```
Hereorg.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Remote connections to this server are not allowed, see -tcpAllowOthers [90117-184]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:83)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I given below command in partner as well as my computer but still I am getting the same error.

http://www.windows-commandline.com/enable-remote-desktop-command-line/

Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: Is H2 running in server mode?

Comment: You mean to say on Generic H2 (Server) . I tried it on browser and it runs perfect but not through Given java code.

Comment: The H2 server made not be in TCP mode

Comment: What can i do to be in TCP Mode

Comment: You could take a look at [this](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server)

Comment: I did but still not able , Please help to resolve

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the H2 server with the `-tcpAllowOthers` option. This option is not enabled by default for security reasons.